# Trouble uploading file ASP.NET MVC3. XML file to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, http-post

I'm attempting to upload an xml file to my site. However, regardless of which file I attempt to upload, the HttpPostedFileBase element in my code is null. I don't understand why this is. I've followed all the examples I can find on uploading files and it doesn't seem to make any sense. This is the controller method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase xmlFile)
    {
        if (xmlFile != null && xmlFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile.InputStream);
            // other logic later
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("UploadFailed");    
    }
```

and the cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"   }))
{
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a wrong name. The action argument is called `xmlFile` whereas your file input is called `file`. You need to be consistent in your naming conventions:

```
<input type="file" name="xmlFile" />
```

I also invite you to checkout Phil Haack's [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) on this subject.